# Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Call to a member function prepare() on string in

Tags: php, mysql

Estoy intentando guardar los datos de un formulario PHP en una base de datos, y al guardar me arroja el siguiente mensaje:

> Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Call to a member function prepare() on string in C:\xampp\htdocs\ecommerce\admin\ins_inventario.php:56 Stack trace: #0 {main} thrown in C:\xampp\htdocs\ecommerce\admin\ins_inventario.php on line 56"

Mi código es el siguiente:

```
<?php
include '../extend/headerphp.php';
include '../extend/alertas.php';

if($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == 'POST'){
    $clave = sha1(rand(0000,9999).rand(00,99));
    $producto = htmlentities($_POST['producto']);
    $cantidad = htmlentities($_POST['cantidad']);
    $precio = htmlentities($_POST['precio']);
    $categoria = htmlentities($_POST['categoria']);
    $descripcion = htmlentities($_POST['descripcion']);

    //redimensionar imagen

    $ruta = $_FILES['imagen']['tmp_name'];
    $imagen = $_FILES['imagen']['name'];

    if($ruta != ''){

        $ancho = 500;
        $alto = 400;
        $info = pathinfo($imagen);
        $tamano = getimagesize($ruta);
        $width = $tamano[0];
        $heigth = $tamano[1];

        if($info['extension'] == 'jpg' || $info['extension'] == 'JPG' || 
        $info['extension'] == 'jpeg' || $info['extension'] == 'JPEG')
        {
            $imagenvieja = imagecreatefromjpeg($ruta);
            $nueva = imagecreatetruecolor($ancho, $alto);
            imagecopyresampled($nueva,$imagenvieja,0,0,0,0,$ancho,$alto,$width,$heigth);
            $copia = 'foto_producto/'.$clave.'jpg';
            imagejpeg($nueva,$copia);
        }elseif ($info['extension'] == 'png' || $info['extension'] == 'PNG')
        {
            $imagenvieja = imagecreatefrompng($ruta);
            $nueva = imagecreatetruecolor($ancho, $alto);
            imagecopyresampled($nueva,$imagenvieja,0,0,0,0,$ancho,$alto,$width,$heigth);
            $copia = 'foto_producto/'.$clave.'png';
            imagepng($nueva,$copia);
        }else{
            echo alerta('El formato no es aceptable','inventario.php');
        }



    }else{
        $copia = 'foto_producto/producto.png';
    }

}else{
echo alerta('Utiliza el formulario','inventario.php');
}
$con = "";
$ins = $con->prepare("INSERT INTO inventario VALUES (DEFAULT, :clave,:producto,:cantidad,:precio,:categoria,:descripcion,:foto)");
    $ins->bindparam(':clave',$clave);
    $ins->bindparam(':producto',$producto);
    $ins->bindparam(':cantidad',$cantidad);
    $ins->bindparam(':categoria',$categoria);
    $ins->bindparam(':foto',$copia);

    if($ins->execute()){
        echo alerta('El producto fue guardado','inventario.php');
        $ins = null;
        $con = null;
    }else{
        echo alerta('El producto no pudo ser guardado','inventario.php');
    }

?>
</body>
</html>
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Estoy aprendiendo esto pero aun no manejo mucho PHP y no sé a qué va relacionado este error:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Estás tratando de hacer un prepare de un `string` y que además está vacío:

```
$con = "";
$ins = $con->prepare("INSERT INTO inventario VALUES (DEFAULT, :clave,:producto,:cantidad,:precio,:categoria,:descripcion,:foto)");
```

`prepare()` es una función de la clase **mysqli**, para poder usarla antes debes de instanciar un objeto de dicha clase:

```
$mysqli = new mysqli("localhost", "my_user", "my_password", "world");
```

Para después poderlo usar de una manera similar a esto:

```
$stmt = $mysqli->prepare("SELECT District FROM City WHERE Name=?";
```

**Referencia:** [mysqli.prepare](http://php.net/manual/es/mysqli.prepare.php)

Comment: $mysqli = new mysqli("localhost", "my_user", "my_password", "world"); disculpa mi poco conocimiento, **"world"** a que hace referencia? es lo único que no me queda claro para poder corregir

Comment: El "world" hace referencia a la base de datos a la que quieras crear la conexión, partiendo de que en un mismo **host** podemos tener varias. La **API** de **PHP** está muy bien documentada, y una gran parte de ella se encuentra traducida al idioma de Cervantes, te recomiendo que la uses para despejar las dudas que seguro que te irán surgiendo entorno a este lenguaje de programación. http://php.net/manual/es/

Comment: Muchas gracias, la información fue muy útil